# Dropdown merged to an edit field (with autocomplete)

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I´m a begginer so excuse if it´s anything very basic.

Here´s my question:

I´d like to have a dropdown field. So user could click to the arrow to see the options and choose one.

But this same dropdown should also allow user to type anything and (like Google does) the options (already loaded by dropdown) start to be suggested in a poup below.

For example....imagine a dropdown where you have a big list of professions (designer, teacher, director...)

You could use the arrow to expand the list, navigate and select the profession you want...But..you could also start typing T...so any profession starting with T are displayed in a popup below...easily allowing to select the correct.

I have no idea on how I could create such feature? Do you have any tip?

Would be possible using CSS3 only? or Jquery?

Thank you very much

Best Regards
Gustavo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is a excelente plugin called jQuery Choosen.
Using jQuery you can initialize this way:

```
<select data-placeholder="Choose a option..." class="my-chosen"></select>

$(".my-chosen").chosen({no_results_text: "No results matched"});
```

Take a look: http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/
Download from: https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/